Can't get file because logged in is not kept
I'm encountering the same situation which is described in this page How to requests.Session().get if website does not keep me logged in? with another website:

Trying to download an executable on this page: https://www.wibu.com/fr/telechargements/developpeurs/programmes-developpeurs.html
When I click on download, it asks me to login first
Then it redirects to another page where the download starts

I tested several combinations without success. This is what I currently have:
s = requests.session()
headers = {
           "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:127.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/127.0",
           'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3'
          }
payload = {
            "user": "dupont",
            "pass": "a_password"
          }
r = s.post("https://www.wibu.com/us/secure-login.html?return_url=%2Fus%2Fsupport%2Fdeveloper%2Fdownloads-developer-software%2Ffile%2Fdownload%2F13734.html&cHash=f839c2633b7143d3fb47e9bf75f5851f", headers=headers, data= payload, allow_redirects=True)
print(response.status_code) # If the request went Ok we usually get a 200 status.
            
try:
    response.raise_for_status()
except requests.exceptions.HTTPError:
    print('oops bad status code {} on request!'.format(response.status_code))
else:
    print('our login redirected to: {}'.format(response.url))
            
r = s.get("https://www.wibu.com/us/support/developer/downloads-developer-software/file/download/13734.html?tx_wibudownloads_downloadlist%5BdirectDownload%5D=directDownload&tx_wibudownloads_downloadlist%5BuseAwsS3%5D=0&cHash=d5bbc5201225cca370f9e88cb726a93e", headers=headers, allow_redirects=True)
            
open(os.path.join(dest_path, "test.deb"), "wb").write(r.content)

I always finish where I'm not logged in.
Do you have any suggestion?
I tested several URLs, POST, GET, several combination but without success.

I clicked around a bit and it does seem to offer direct download links if you don't want to log in. For example, https://www.wibu.com/fr/telechargements/utilisateurs/telechargement-logiciels-utilisateurs/file/download/13650.html offers a direct download link https://www.wibu.com/fr/telechargements/utilisateurs/telechargement-logiciels-utilisateurs/file/download/13650.html?tx_wibudownloads_downloadlist%5BdirectDownload%5D=directDownload&tx_wibudownloads_downloadlist%5BuseAwsS3%5D=0&cHash=8dba7ab094dec6267346f04fce2a2bcd

yes. There is a public part with files that anyone can download. But there is also a private part with specific downloads for developer where log in is mandatory. This is this private part i want to access with my developer credentials.

200 status code does not mean a successful login, the site also sends more data in the payload than just the user & pass, try making sure you're actually logged in first.

Finally, by completing the payload with WIBU specific attributes, i success to login.
